# Symfony 3.3.10 RunTime exception Class mismatch

Tags: symfony

Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: "Symfony\Bundle\FrameWorkBundle\Controller\Controller" vs "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller".

In my controller i have this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameWorkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class MainController extends Controller
{
public function homepageAction()
{
    return $this->render('main/index.html.twig');
}
}
```

Comment: The case sensitivity was a recent change.  Have you looked in the various change logs to see what else is different?  What version are you upgrading from?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just fix what the error tells you? (sorry if that sounds harsh)

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
```

instead of

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameWorkBundle\Controller\Controller;
```

Comment: Hm, i have now problem with Routing. I can't get them to work. If i edit app/config/routes.yml it gives me that it's not a valid YML file.

What to do to get them work, the documentation of Symfony didn't explain at all.